# Random Button in android

Tags: java, android, android-studio, button, tags

I have 1 TextView that provides me two randomly generated numbers 3 + 4 for example, and there are 4 buttons, but a random button has right answer (7) and other 3 - randomly generated numbers. I have no idea how to set a right answer to a random button. What should i use? tags?

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest to use the Random class here.

```
public void set_options(int ans){ //ans should contain the original answer

  Random random;
  int a;
  a = random.nextInt(4);
  switch(a){
     case 0:
        //Set option 1 to answer
        option1.setText(ans.toString());

     case 1:
        //Set option 2 to answer
        option2.setText(ans.toString());

     case 2:
        //Set option 3 to answer
        option3.setText(ans.toString());

     case 3:
        //Set option 4 to answer
        option4.setText(ans.toString());

  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The best way would be to do this.

```
Button option1,option2,option3,option4;

private void addOptions(String answer){
    int answerOption = new Random().nextInt(4);

    switch (answerOption){
        case 0:
            option1.setText(answer);
            int option1R = new Random().nextInt(99);
            int option2R = new Random().nextInt(99);
            int option3R = new Random().nextInt(99);
            if (option1R != Integer.parseInt(answer)) {
                option2.setText(new Random().nextInt(99));
            }
            if (option2R != Integer.parseInt(answer)) {
                option3.setText(new Random().nextInt(99));
            }
            if (option3R != Integer.parseInt(answer)) {
                option4.setText(new Random().nextInt(99));
            }
            option4.setOnClickListener(v -> {
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "wrong answer click", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            });
            option3.setOnClickListener(v -> {
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "wrong answer click", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            });
            option2.setOnClickListener(v -> {
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "wrong answer click", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            });
            option1.setOnClickListener(v -> {
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "correct answer clicked.", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            });
            break;
        case 1:
            option1.setText(answer);
            int option1R2 = new Random().nextInt(99);
            int option2R2 = new Random().nextInt(99);
            int option3R2 = new Random().nextInt(99);
            if (option1R2 != Integer.parseInt(answer)) {
                option1.setText(new Random().nextInt(99));
            }
            if (option2R2 != Integer.parseInt(answer)) {
                option3.setText(new Random().nextInt(99));
            }
            if (option3R2 != Integer.parseInt(answer)) {
                option4.setText(new Random().nextInt(99));
            }
            option4.setOnClickListener(v -> {
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "wrong answer click", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            });
            option3.setOnClickListener(v -> {
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "wrong answer click", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            });
            option2.setOnClickListener(v -> {
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "correct answer click", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            });
            option1.setOnClickListener(v -> {
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "wrong answer clicked.", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            });
            break;
        case 2:
            option1.setText(answer);
            int option1R22 = new Random().nextInt(99);
            int option2R22 = new Random().nextInt(99);
            int option3R22 = new Random().nextInt(99);
            if (option1R22 != Integer.parseInt(answer)) {
                option1.setText(new Random().nextInt(99));
            }
            if (option2R22 != Integer.parseInt(answer)) {
                option2.setText(new Random().nextInt(99));
            }
            if (option3R22 != Integer.parseInt(answer)) {
                option4.setText(new Random().nextInt(99));
            }
            option4.setOnClickListener(v -> {
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "wrong answer click", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            });
            option3.setOnClickListener(v -> {
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "correct answer click", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            });
            option2.setOnClickListener(v -> {
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "wrong answer click", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            });
            option1.setOnClickListener(v -> {
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "wrong answer clicked.", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            });
            break;
        case 3:
            option1.setText(answer);
            int option1R222 = new Random().nextInt(99);
            int option2R222 = new Random().nextInt(99);
            int option3R222 = new Random().nextInt(99);
            if (option1R222 != Integer.parseInt(answer)) {
                option1.setText(new Random().nextInt(99));
            }
            if (option2R222 != Integer.parseInt(answer)) {
                option2.setText(new Random().nextInt(99));
            }
            if (option3R222 != Integer.parseInt(answer)) {
                option4.setText(new Random().nextInt(99));
            }
            option4.setOnClickListener(v -> {
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "correct answer click", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            });
            option3.setOnClickListener(v -> {
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "wrong answer click", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            });
            option2.setOnClickListener(v -> {
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "wrong answer click", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            });
            option1.setOnClickListener(v -> {
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "wrong answer clicked.", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            });
            break;
    }
}
```

Note the task of finding the views by id or using binding is your task.